# Is windows socket (winsocket) available on Mac OS?

Tags: c, winsock

I am trying to use windows socket and C for a new project, I am on Mac OS and have gcc C compiler installed:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
```

This pulls up a error:

```
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (/Users/thisismyuser/Desktop/c++networkprogram/networkprogram.c).C/C++(1696)
cannot open source file "winsock2.h"
```

So I went down a rabbit hole and some links will say that it is available on mac os and some aren't.

Is it avaialble on mac os?

I am using VS code

Comment: I'd avoid using winsock, in favour of the native networking stack. Have a read of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsock. Try to identify which functions come from that header file, then look for native/Unix equivalents instead.

Comment: No. You get the BSD Sockets API.

Answer (score 0):

This uses the Win32 API, so it will not work on MacOS, nor will it work on Linux.

You can run Windows 10 (for example) in a virtual machine, or you can use Wine to run such programs. You will need a virtual machine for development.

You can also use [BSD Sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets).